# reset router password without changing settings/get settings before reset?

Tags: router, password-recovery

I seem to have lost the router password to my wndr3700 and I need to add a new portforward to my already large list, thing is, I know I can do a factory reset, but that will also lose all of my portfowards and other settings. Is there some way of resetting just the password, or saving the settings so that I can restore them after the reset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official [Netgear answer](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/12744/kw/password) is :

> Unfortunately, there is no way to
>   recover a lost or forgotten password
>   from a router or access point; you
>   will need to reset the device to
>   factory defaults.

If you have ever taken a backup of your router's configuration, you can use it to recover the password using the [Nirsoft RouterPassView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/router_password_recovery.html) :

> The backup file of the router usually
>   contains important data like your ISP
>   user name/password, the login password
>   of the router, and wireless network
>   keys. If you lost one of these
>   password/keys, but you still have a
>   backup file of your router
>   configuration, RouterPassView might
>   help you to recover your lost password
>   from your router file.

[image]

Comment: sadly, I set this router up before I thought of taking backups. after resetting it, now I will! also, selecting as answer because of that nifty tool for future people

Answer (score 1):

More than likely not possible (at least, easily) since the router doesn't have a way of connecting that wouldn't require you to authenticate. Without physically taking the devices non-volatile storage out and reading it, I don't think this is possible.

I know it's repeated a lot, but it's essential -- keep good, regular backups of both your data *and* hardware settings for devices with complex setups.

Comment: arg, I thought so, but it was worth trying to ask