# Password Recovery from Router without Reset

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt, password-recovery

Background Story: Previous Technician for a small business set up a network for a customer. The Technician went AWOL (The small business owner is a close friend, and I knew the previous technician as well long story short, drugs) The Small Business owner has approached me to make some modifications to his Wireless - LAN. One request was to obtain the password for his wireless (Easily done it was saved on a laptop under Windows just had to click show password) His second request was to make two wireless access points from the Wireless Router. One for Customers and one for the Employees. Something  I can easily do as well, but this is where I ran into trouble. The previous technician set a password on the router itself. The password I am referring to is the one you get when navigating to 192.168.1.1. I have tried several "Known" combinations by the owner of the Small Business to no avail. I am currently working on a Brute Force method to try to grab the information, but this is taking a while due to multiple log-ins that are a possibility plus cracking the password. Now I am sure you are asking, why go through all of this trouble when you can just reset to defaults using this button in the back? The answer is there were special settings set up for an invoice program this Small Business unit is using I am not sure what, but to keep them from experiencing downtime and having to troubleshoot their newly experienced issue caused by me I would rather take the long approach because it isn't that pressing of a manner they just want it done. I have expressed to them that it might take some time. Is there anyway to obtain this password, ie; capturing specific packets while rebooting the router? Potentially mounting the flash memory in a Linux system and pulling information from that? I know this is a very "Grey" area that is why I tried to give a lot of background info before posting this, but I can promise this is completely "White Hat"
Router Model: Linksys WRT54G/GL/GS 
Router Firmware: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (10/10/09) micro

tl;dr How can I obtain a router password from 192.168.1.1/router admin web interface without resetting to defaults?

Comment: Did you try to login to the router with ssh? Please provide info if ssh login is permitted and if login with DD-WRT default root login (user: root; passwd: admin) works. If you can login using ssh, you can change weblogin with the command: setuserpasswd [username] [password]

Comment: Also from the DD-WRT FAQ: Q: I did forget the password I did set, what can I do to access the router's control panel? A: The only way to re-access your router is resetting it to factory defaults. To do this on most router models you have to press the reset button of the router for appr. 20sec when powering the router up. Please keep in mind that this means that all settings you made are lost.

Comment: You may want to see http://superuser.com/questions/303398/how-can-we-recover-the-router-password-recover-not-reset